# Range to cells with xldown

Tags: excel, vba

hey I have this part of code

```
Range("A2:BY2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
```

I want to convert into Cells to have my code quicker
I tried this

```
With Worksheets("BLOTTER")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(77, 2).End(xlDown))
End With
```

but doesnt seems to select the good range
Thank you

Comment: How about:  `set rng = activesheet.usedrange.cells`

Comment: Why are you selecting this range?  Do you want to perform an operation?  I can show you how to select that range but you should avoid using .Select if at all possible, if you could enlighten me as to why you are selecting this range I might be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help becuase I'm not sure I remember the end properly, but it doesn't appear you are using the right syntax with your set rng statement... try this:

```
Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 2).Address & ":" & .Cells(77, 2).End(xlDown).Address)
```

If I'm remembering properly, the range needs to be set as a string, or at least I always did it that way, and the .Address property returns the string name of the cell you referenced, e.g. .Cells(1, 2).Address returns "$A$2".

Answer (score 0):

This will select the range you want, but using .Select should be avoided.  Why do you want to select this range? A copy/paste?  Formatting?  You don't need to select the range for any of those operations.

```
Sub getRange()


Dim rng As Range

Set rng = Range("A2:BY2")

rng.Select

End Sub
```